# OSGi Blueprint configuration: injecting a list of bean references

Tags: java, osgi, blueprint-osgi

I am trying to inject a list of beans in a list property in my blueprint.xml (similar to what you would do in [Spring configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-collection-elements)):

blueprint.xml:

```
<blueprint
  xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0
    http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">

<bean id="myBean" class="MyClass" />

<bean id="anotherBean" class="AnotherClass">
  <property name="myClasses">
    <list>
      <ref bean="myBean" />
    <list>
  </property>
</bean>

</blueprint>
```

AnotherClass:

```
public class AnotherClass {
   private List<MyClass> myClasses;

   public void setMyClasses(List<MyClass> classes) {
     this.myClasses = classes;
   }
}
```

I had a look at the [Blueprint XML schema](http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd) and the [R4.2 enterprise spec](http://www.osgi.org/Download/File?url=/download/r4v42/r4.enterprise.pdf) (which we are using) and found nothing suitable. But this is just such an obvious use case that I can't believe that this is not possible.

**Any suggestions what I am missing here and how to do this?**

Answer (score 6):

I came across same issue and found an answer [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-osgiblueprint/index.html). In ref element, change from bean to component-id.

```
<bean id="myBean" class="MyClass" />

<bean id="anotherBean" class="AnotherClass">
  <property name="myClasses">
    <list>
      <ref component-id="myBean" />
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

The list element should actually work natively provided you are not suffering from a malformed xml problem as found in the example code (assuming a typo for the missing slash in the closing list tag).

Here is a very good slide deck with described usage:

http://www.slideshare.net/gnodet/osgi-blueprint-services-1622424

[original suggestion below may still work but should not be required]

> However, you should still be able to use other spring schema.
>
> Try adding the util schema:
>
> ```
> xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
> ```
>
> and then namespacing the list element:
>
> ```
> <util:list>
>     <ref bean="myBean" />
> </util:list>
> ```
>
> (this works seamlessly in spring because the beans namespace imports several other namespaces, including "util", automatically)